# specifying all classes in ontology as range of owl property

Tags: rdf, owl, semantics, rdfs

I am designing OWL DL Ontology for my internal use (X), there is a very abstract property(x:relatedTo) that I need to set its range as all the classes live in another imported ontology (Y), such that

```
x:relatedTo rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty . 
x:relateTo rdfs:range y:??? .
```

I need such construct in order to allow the user to assert any class in X can be related to any class Y for semantic similarity calculations. Any ideas ?

P.S : my requirement is to isolate X classes from Y classes to prevent users from defining acyclic edges, in other terms, any x class can not relate to any other x class in X

Comment: There is no such construct for "all classes". You can only define classes explicitly by using their names.

Comment: I know that, but I was wondering if any SO user could have an idea to extend this

Comment: Extend what? The OWL semantics?

Comment: Possibly classes in Y have common parent class or something else in common that is suitable to write appropriate class expression...

Comment: If I read you correctly, x:relateTo is meant to link a class from X to a class from Y. If that is so, then remember that you should not use rdfs:range with the classes from Y, not even with a common superclass of all those classes (as suggested by @stanislav-kralin). "P rdfs:range C" means that property P points to *instances* of class C, *not* to C itself (nor to subclasses of C).